# Can't see my raspberry pi when connected to my office's VPN

Tags: vpn, home-networking, raspberry-pi

Normally I can get to my pi on the home network via local IP 192.168.1.7. However, when connecting to a VPN, I can't.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 on my home network.

**Is there a way to access local network assets while connecting via a vpn to another network?**

Comment: What subnet is your VPN on?

Comment: You probably need to enabled [split-tunneling](http://superuser.com/search?q=vpn+split+tunnel) on your VPN connection (if it allows it). Since you haven't told us which OS and which VPN client you're using, there's not much more we can offer. Please add more detail to your question.